# How to write to SRAM on STm32 nucleo board (mbed)

Tags: c, stm32, mbed

I want to store a simple integer in the SRAM on the chip. (Cortex M4)
The program I use is mbed online.
I know that the address for the SRAM starts at 0x2000 0000 and the chip has 4KB of said memory.

I have read the datasheet and the bitbanding part, but it just doesn't make sense to me.

Can someone please explain to me how I can store for example the number 5 in the SRAM and read it again?

Current code is like this(c is an integer that the user changes with a button):
    `if(c==100){
    temp=c;
    MBX_B0 = 1;      // Word write
    temp = MBX_B7;   // Word read

    TIMER_B0 = temp; // Byte write 
    return TIMER_B7; // Byte read
}
    pc.printf("%d",temp);`

It just stops running once c==100
THE VALUE SHOULD BE SAVED EVEN AFTER POWER DOWN.

Comment: If you haven't already, read this: [mbed Memory-Model](https://developer.mbed.org/handbook/Memory-Model).

Comment: There is no STM32 model with a Cortex-M4 core and 4K SRAM at 0x20000000. What controller are you working with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT, your question COMPLETELY changes the answer as you are not interested in SRAM writing at all but flash/eeprom...

So adding a major section to this answer, your comment is critical here:

> But Is the value stored even after power down? Isn't that what SRAM
>   would do instead of normal RAM? RAM=lose value when no power,
>   SRAM=Keep value when no power?

SRAM means Static RAM, RAM means Random Access Memory.  Now RAM by that definition can be safe to use for things like a ROM (Read Only Memory) as the Random part has to do with addressing, can I address any random address I want or can I only read this thing using linear one address after the other per some rules.

The convention is that ROM is non-volatile and RAM is volatile which are the relevant terms here.  ROM implementations are not technically read only  PROM is programmable rom which means writeable, so that kinda breaks down the term EPROM electrically programmable, EEPROM is electrically eraseable and programmable.  And flash is a newer technology electrically eraseable and programmable rom or non-volatile storage.

Volatile in this sense means it can or cannot survive a power cycle.  volaitle means it cannot non-volatile means it can.

The S in SRAM is for Static sure which the term implies it might survive esp when you learn for DRAM the D means dynamic, and perfectly fine to assume one survives a power cycle and the other does not but unfortunately that is not what they refer to.  Instead in both cases they have to do with memory that remains powered, they are both volatile memories.  go look these up on wikipedia.  Static uses four transistors lets say, two gates with feedback in a classic flip flop implementation, you write the bit high or low and so long as the power doesnt turn off it stays that value it doesnt forget (so long as the power stays on).  DRAM though uses one transistor and to some extent relies heavily on the capacitance in that transistor, kind of like a lame rechargable battery, you want it to remember a 1 you have to charge it up and it discharges quickly (as in milliseconds) so you have to constantly remind it it is a one or a zero (refresh).

so static ram is static in the sense that we only have to tell it once and it remembers, dynamic ram is dynamic in the sense that we tell the dram system what that bit is and as a system we have to keep reminding it, this is done by reading the bit then reprogramming/charging that bit at a certain frequency.

DRAM is cheap, can pack four times the number of bits into the same number of transistors, SRAM is fast dont have the complicated overhead nor refresh cycles getting in the way, it is just gates so can run as fast as other gates as fast as the gates doing other things (processing instructions).

A microcontroller will have some form of non-volatile storage in it ROM, PROM, EEPROM or flash (of which there are now various flavors).  sometimes you have both flash and eeprom the eeprom for the kind of thing you may be asking for here, and sometimes for reverse compatibility reasons they have an eeprom legacy interface but it is really using the main flash for storage.  In any case you have to look at the documentation for your chip and or chip family.  These days it is common (although there are many exceptions) to have the ability in application to write to an on chip non-volatile memory (eeprom/flash).  And the documentation tells you how to do this.

And that is all great but some free advice is you can wear out your flash if you do this wrong, in hours or days...literally...The part can be trashed.  Ideally you want support on your board to detect the power going down, at the same time have enough bulk capacitance or a battery or both to keep the board/device alive long enough for the worst case amount of time it needs to save the non-volatile information (ideally confirming first that the values have changed otherwise dont burn an erase cycle).  Quite simple to implement, but still better than wearing out flash.

Lots of solutions and opinions on how to not wear out your flash, and sadly some of the flash hardware has logic that does write leveling, which if both software and hardware are trying to spread things out to reduce the wear on the flash they can work against each other and do more harm than good.

The number of supported write cycles for your part should be documented in the datasheet, you exceed that for the lifetime of the product you built with this device, it can forget what you wrote.  That is the minimum supported it might say 10000 writes but in testing you might get to 100,000 and have a device that still works. Doesnt mean all the reset of them will exceed the rating in the datasheet so you can work backward from that, if I get a new value every so many units of time and the lifetime of the product is I hope to be so many units of time, then I cannot save more than some simple math units of time (per storage location/erase boundary, etc).

so start by learning how, in application, to erase a block you are not using, and then write something to it then see if it is there when you power back up, try eeprom if you have it if not flash.  generally well documented and pretty easy to do on these STM32 devices.  then once you know how to do it then start to worry about how often you feel you need to do it.

Ever notice in some cars that when you turn them "off" and back on the clock still works and the radio remembers your favorite stations or the air condition remembers the last temperature and fan speed you used.  but if you disconnect the battery some or all of that is lost.  they are not using non-volatile storage they are using ram (SRAM) and the power simply went off, they are relying on a battery backup.  Motherboards did and maybe still do this for your "CMOS" or "BIOS" settings.  battery backed ram basically in that the ram doesnt lose power, the main power may go off but a battery is keeping the ram powered.  That is another design solution you can use, a battery or super cap(acitor), might assume you never need to store to flash, if like the car stereo, the battery dies the oh well.

Granted all of this requires my prior answer, in order to get at the registers that control the eeprom/flash you need to know how to access them from your program:

First and foremost bit banding is not required here (to store/load some value to/from ram), are you asking how to write to and read from specific addresses in ram or are you asking how to use bit banding?  Normally you wouldnt use bit banding with ram, the feature is there for example to change a subset of the bits in a register where the designers have for some reason packed separate items into the same register (things like gpio pin configurations make sense, and you might want to change the configuration for a single pin without a read-modify-write in software (hardware may still have to do the read-modify-write))

Sure you could use the bitbanding feature on ram, if the cortex-m allows it I would need to re-read that, doesnt necessarily make sense unless you are that tightly starved for ram that you need to be packing separate things into a single word (like bitfields but dont even start with that)...

```
#define BITBAND_SRAM_REF   0x20000000
#define BITBAND_SRAM_BASE  0x22000000
#define BITBAND_SRAM(a,b)  ((BITBAND_SRAM_BASE + (a-BITBAND_SRAM_REF)*32 + (b*4)))
#define BITBAND_PERI_REF   0x40000000
#define BITBAND_PERI_BASE  0x42000000
#define BITBAND_PERI(a,b)  ((BITBAND_PERI_BASE + (a-BITBAND_PERI_REF)*32  + (b*4)))
#define MAILBOX            0x20004000
#define TIMER              0x40004000
#define MBX_B0             *((volatile unsigned int*)(BITBAND_SRAM(MAILBOX,0)))
#define MBX_B7             *((volatile unsigned int*)(BITBAND_SRAM(MAILBOX,7)))
#define TIMER_B0           *((volatile unsigned char*)(BITBAND_PERI(TIMER,0)))
#define TIMER_B7           *((volatile unsigned char*)(BITBAND_PERI(TIMER,7)))


MBX_B0 = 1;
```

So none of this is special, or related to the cortex-m or arm, just basic C code.  MBX_B0 is a macro you work the macro backward

```
#define MBX_B0             *((volatile unsigned int*)(BITBAND_SRAM(MAILBOX,0)))
```

then

```
#define MAILBOX            0x20004000
#define BITBAND_SRAM(a,b)  ((BITBAND_SRAM_BASE + (a-BITBAND_SRAM_REF)*32 + (b*4)))
#define BITBAND_SRAM_BASE  0x22000000
#define BITBAND_SRAM_REF   0x20000000
```

so

```
0x22000000+(0x20004000-0x20000000)*32 + (0*4)

= 0x22080000
```

The volatile unsigned int thing is just a C syntax way to take some constant like 0x22080009 and say this is the address to something I want to point to so

```
MBX_B0 = 1;
```

means write a 0x00000001 to address 0x22080000 but since this is using bit banding, that means set bit 1 of bit 0 of address 0x20004000 (bit banding being very specific to these arm cortex-m cores)

If you just wanted to write the value 5 to some location in memory you could have just

```
#define SOME_ADD *((volatile unsigned int*)(0x20001234)
unsigned int x;
SOME_ADD = 5;
x = SOME_ADD;
```

and to see this all done for you you can just try it:

```
#define BITBAND_SRAM_REF   0x20000000
#define BITBAND_SRAM_BASE  0x22000000
#define BITBAND_SRAM(a,b)  ((BITBAND_SRAM_BASE + (a-BITBAND_SRAM_REF)*32 + (b*4)))
#define MAILBOX            0x20004000
#define MBX_B0             *((volatile unsigned int*)(BITBAND_SRAM(MAILBOX,0)))

#define SOME_ADD *((volatile unsigned int*)(0x20001234))

unsigned int fun ( void )
{
    unsigned int x;

    MBX_B0 = 1;

    SOME_ADD = 5;
    x = SOME_ADD;

}
```

arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -O2 so.c -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e3a0c001    mov r12, #1
   4:   e3a02005    mov r2, #5
   8:   e59f1010    ldr r1, [pc, #16]   ; 20 <fun+0x20>
   c:   e59f3010    ldr r3, [pc, #16]   ; 24 <fun+0x24>
  10:   e581c000    str r12, [r1]
  14:   e5832234    str r2, [r3, #564]  ; 0x234
  18:   e5933234    ldr r3, [r3, #564]  ; 0x234
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  20:   22080000    andcs   r0, r8, #0
  24:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
```

the processor loads the address 0x20001000 and in this case the assembler has chosen to add the immediate 0x234 to that rather than put the whole 0x20001234 in the address loaded, six of one... no different cost either way, as written the compiler didnt need to align the loaded value.

Now if you are not needing to hit a specific address (0x20001234 or some peripheral register, etc) then simply

```
unsigned int some_value;
void fun ( void )
{
    some_value = 5;
}
```

need to compile and link it to see the whole story:

```
00000004 <fun>:
   4:   e3a02005    mov r2, #5
   8:   e59f3004    ldr r3, [pc, #4]    ; 14 <fun+0x10>
   c:   e5832000    str r2, [r3]
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
  14:   20000000    andcs   r0, r0, r0

Disassembly of section .bss:

20000000 <some_value>:
20000000:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

and the code has now stored the number 5 to some location in ram (chosen by the linker).

on the bitbanding side of things if you read your arm documentation you will find that it is not always supported, in some cores it is an optional feature which means when they compile the chip they can choose to not include it.  And if for examaple this is a particular st chip or family you may find that they forgot to document one or both of the bitband addresses (0x22000000, 0x42000000) but have it in the library.

Personaly I am not a fan of the volatile pointer trick, I have seen compilers fail to produce the right instruction so I write a tiny two line assembly function that I can abstract all such accesses through which has a great side effect of forcing an abstraction like you would have in a linux or other driver anyway.  Allows the code to be much more useful, can abstract the access to a software simulation, can abstract the access to a logic simulation, can abstract through mmap, can use in a kernel driver, can add a printf layer for debugging that way, single place to set a breakpoint if you prefer that type of debugging, can implement with the couple of lines of asm for bare metal, or can use a generic macro/define to do the volatile pointer thing if you prefer that. YMMV.

Note local variables

```
void fun ( void )
{
    unsigned int some_value;
    some_value = 5;
}
```

do not necessarily end up in ram, they ideally go on the stack, but can get optimized out if you optimize (recommended for a resource starved device like a microcontroller unless MISRA or some other requirement prevents you from using the optimizer).  The above code of course is completely dead code, results in a simple return:

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Comment: you can also create an array if you want to compile time allocate (dont do runtime allocation, this is an mcu so no reason for it at all you OWN all the ram just use it) some amount of ram to be used by the application,  if for some reason that block has to be aligned (not sure why for these devices) then just use a fixed address like the volatile pointer thing and as the responsible programmer and software engineer, avoid running into ram being used for other reasons by doing a proper design.

Comment: But Is the value stored even after power down? Isn't that what SRAM would do instead of normal RAM? RAM=lose value when no power, SRAM=Keep value when no power?

Comment: @AlexM. No, SRAM still loses it's values when powered down.  SRAM retains data in its memory as long as power is being supplied, unlike DRAM which to be periodically refreshed. If you want to retain values across power cycles, you need to use non-volatile memory such as Flash or EEPROM.

Answer (score 0):

While reading about [bitbanding](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/02/08/bit-banding/), I found this code in an [Application Note](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/CHDJHIDF.html)

I copied it out and compiled it.  This should get you started.

```
#define BITBAND_SRAM_REF   0x20000000
#define BITBAND_SRAM_BASE  0x22000000
#define BITBAND_SRAM(a,b)  ((BITBAND_SRAM_BASE + (a-BITBAND_SRAM_REF)*32 + (b*4))) // Convert SRAM address
#define BITBAND_PERI_REF   0x40000000
#define BITBAND_PERI_BASE  0x42000000
#define BITBAND_PERI(a,b)  ((BITBAND_PERI_BASE + (a-BITBAND_PERI_REF)*32  + (b*4))) // Convert PERI address
#define MAILBOX            0x20004000
#define TIMER              0x40004000 // Mailbox bit 0
#define MBX_B0             *((volatile unsigned int*)(BITBAND_SRAM(MAILBOX,0))) // Mailbox bit 7
#define MBX_B7             *((volatile unsigned int*)(BITBAND_SRAM(MAILBOX,7))) // Timer bit 0
#define TIMER_B0           *((volatile unsigned char*)(BITBAND_PERI(TIMER,0)))  // Timer bit 7
#define TIMER_B7           *((volatile unsigned char*)(BITBAND_PERI(TIMER,7)))

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int temp = 0;

    MBX_B0 = 1;      // Word write    
    temp = MBX_B7;   // Word read    
    TIMER_B0 = temp; // Byte write    
    return TIMER_B7; // Byte read
}
```

> Can someone please explain to me how I can store for example the number 5 in the SRAM and read it again?

In the sample code above, `temp` is in RAM.

If you dont care about using bitbanding right now, just declaring a variable `int x = 5` stores the number 5 in RAM.

Comment: Thank you, but one think I don't understand is how exactly do I store the number, do I declare it it underneath your code? Do I change the `temp`? One more thing is how do I read the variable afterwards, I updated my question, could you maybe take another look at it